# Device tree binds the desired device driver at boot time in Linux (raspberry pi)

Tags: c, linux, kernel, driver

I have written one platform driver (dummy driver) and want to know that how can i use device tree or "where to add my device node ?" in device tree so that my driver automatically loaded at boot time and prob() called automatically. and,
I don't know that in which directory the device tree finds the particular driver to bind ?
thanks in anticipation!!

Answer (score 0):

For it you need use the includes:

```
#include <linux/of.h>       
#include <linux/of_device.h>
```

And in your device declarations (note I'm using `<you thing here>` for you change with your device names):

```
#ifdef CONFIG_OF
static const struct of_device_id <your_device_name_here>_dt_match_table[] = {
    { .compatible = "<your compatible string here>" },
    { },
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, <your_device_name_here>_dt_match_table);
#endif

static struct platform_driver <your_device_name_here>_driver = {
    .probe = <your_device_name_here>_probe,
    .remove = <your_device_name_here>_remove,
    .driver = {
        .name = "<your_device_name_here>",
        .of_match_table = of_match_ptr(clap_sensor_dt_match_table),
    },
};
module_platform_driver(<your_device_name_here>_driver);
```

With this in your driver you could write the follow in device tree:

```
<your_device_name_here> {
        compatible = "<your compatible string here>";
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&your_pins_pinctrl>;
        label = "trigger";
        trigger-gpios = <&gpio 23 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
};
```

Compatible property the must be the same on the device tree file and your device driver file, so that the kernel can match the information of its node in the device tree with your driver.

And remembering device tree is only for describe hardware, do not use it for store software variables or other software stuffs.

I recommend you study some about device tree pinctrl and gpio. Raspberry foundation has some material for device tree overlays:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/device-tree.md